# Linux /srv directory permissions revert on reboot

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-mint, directory, reboot

I have a problem that the access permissions for group and world access on the `/srv` directory get reverted on reboot.

Whenever I grant the world write access using `sudo chmod a+rwx /srv` then all is well, except that after a reboot, the permissions revert back to the old permissions.

I can reproduce this with a fresh Linux Mint 18 installation in VirtualBox.

After some more testing, it seems that the permissions of `/dev`, `/home`, `/proc`, `/run`, `/sys` and `/var` are reset after reboot as well.

The directories `/bin`, `/boot`, `/cdrom`, `/etc`, `/lib`, `/lib64`, `/lost+found`, `/media`, `/mnt`, `/opt`, `/root`, `/sbin`, `/tmp` and `/usr` are not affected.

I also tried removing all scripts in `/etc/init.d`, in the hope to pinpoint a "smart" init script, but permissions still got reset after reboot. Mint 18 apparently uses systemd by default, I did not try to remove the systemd scripts as that would probably just break the system.

I checked the mount output to see if something strange was mounted, this was not the case as far as I could see (Mount output below).

I tried to reproduce this phenomena with the slightly older Linux Mint 17.3 which I have been using for some time without problems. It seems Mint 17.3 also resets permissions, but not on the `/srv` directory. For completeness, it does reset `/dev`, `/proc`, `/run` and `/sys`.

Hoping to get a clue where to search for, I replaced `/bin/chmod` with a shell script calling the "real" chmod, the shell script additionally logs the chmod call with its parameters to a file on disk. Unfortunately no calls got logged except for my own `chmod a+rwx *` test call.

So I get the feeling some application binary is trying to be smart and "fix" the permissions for me, but which one?

Anybody an idea?

`ls -l` output just after installation:

```
user@system / $ ls -l /
total 96
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:46 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4240 Feb  6 20:51 dev
drwxr-xr-x 150 root root 12288 Feb  6 20:50 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:46 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Feb  6 20:50 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Feb  6 20:44 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 173 root root     0 Feb  6  2017 proc
drwx------   4 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:51 root
drwxr-xr-x  30 root root   940 Feb  6 20:51 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Feb  6 20:50 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Feb  6 20:51 sys
drwxrwxrwt  10 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:51 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Feb  6 20:50 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
user@system / $
```

`ls -l` output after `sudo chmod a+rwx *`

```
user@system / $ ls -lah
total 96
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 bin
drwxrwxrwx   3 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 boot
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:46 cdrom
drwxrwxrwx  19 root root  4240 Feb  6 20:51 dev
drwxrwxrwx 150 root root 12288 Feb  6 20:50 etc
drwxrwxrwx   3 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:46 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Feb  6 20:50 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
drwxrwxrwx  25 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 lib
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 lib64
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 16384 Feb  6 20:44 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 media
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 mnt
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 opt
drwxrwxrwx 167 root root     0 Feb  6  2017 proc
drwxrwxrwx   4 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:51 root
drwxrwxrwx  30 root root   960 Feb  6 20:56 run
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 12288 Feb  6 20:50 sbin
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 srv
drwxrwxrwx  13 root root     0 Feb  6 20:51 sys
drwxrwxrwt  10 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:56 tmp
drwxrwxrwx  10 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 usr
drwxrwxrwx  11 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Feb  6 20:50 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
user@system / $
```

After reboot: (Just to be sure, i did a manual `sync` before rebooting)

```
user@system / $ ls -l
total 96
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 bin
drwxrwxrwx   3 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 boot
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:46 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4240 Feb  6 20:57 dev
drwxrwxrwx 150 root root 12288 Feb  6 20:50 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:46 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Feb  6 20:50 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
drwxrwxrwx  25 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:50 lib
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 lib64
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 16384 Feb  6 20:44 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 media
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 mnt
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 177 root root     0 Feb  6  2017 proc
drwxrwxrwx   4 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:51 root
drwxr-xr-x  29 root root   920 Feb  6 20:57 run
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 12288 Feb  6 20:50 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Feb  6 20:57 sys
drwxrwxrwt  10 root root  4096 Feb  6 20:57 tmp
drwxrwxrwx  10 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Jun 28  2016 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Feb  6 20:50 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
user@system / $
```

mount output:

```
user@system / $ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1132716k,nr_inodes=283179,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=230660k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd,nsroot=/)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.perf_event,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.pids,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices,nsroot=/)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
cgmfs on /run/cgmanager/fs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=230660k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
user@system / $
```

PS While normally having the `/srv` directory world writable is probably a bad idea, in my case I have a separate system in a firewalled environment for embedded development purposes.

Comment: You could try making `/srv` immutable (`chattr +i /srv`), and check post-reboot logs for anything complaining about not being able to reset it.

Comment: Good hint, thanks! Syslog now complains: `systemd-tmpfiles[517]: chmod(/srv) failed: Operation not permitted` - Now I can zero in on the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The permissions were set by systemd-tmpfiles which seems to be documented [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html).

I could solve it by editing `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/home.conf`, I placed a comment before the line `q /srv 0755 - - -`

With thanks to DopeGhoti for helping to pinpoint.